# netstat display Huge amount of "SYN_RCVD" state

Tags: performance, nginx, solaris

netstat display Huge amount of "SYN_RCVD" state on Solaris 11,  it's a nginx reverse server.

```
# netstat -na | awk '/^20/ {++S[$NF]} END {for(a in S) print a, S[a]}'
TIME_WAIT 515
ESTABLISHED 427
SYN_SENT 14
LAST_ACK 223
Connected 9488
FIN_WAIT_1 37
FIN_WAIT_2 167
CLOSING 48
CLOSE_WAIT 11
Idle 5
SYN_RCVD 4437
```

**The server tcp/ip parameters:**

```
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_time_wait_interval
60000
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_keepalive_interval
15000
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_fin_wait_2_flush_interval
67500
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_conn_req_max_q
16384
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_conn_req_max_q0
16384
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_xmit_hiwat
400000
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_recv_hiwat
400000
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_cwnd_max
2097152
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_ip_abort_interval
20000
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_rexmit_interval_initial
4000
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_rexmit_interval_max
10000
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_rexmit_interval_min
3000
# ndd -get /dev/tcp tcp_max_buf
4194304
```

How to tuning this nginx reverse server.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # of conn reqs in SYN_RCVD - "fully-established" connections - 
 those which have finished the 3-way handshake and 
 are waiting to be picked up by an "accept()" call.
```

You should consider tuning your [accept_mutex](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#accept_mutex) `nginx` parameter and may be try different `nginx` [processing method](http://nginx.org/en/docs/events.html#poll), just to get if it is real reason.

Comment: nginx.conf: `worker_connections 66536;  devpoll_events 1;  multi_accept on;`

Comment: @Clinton, I see your options, but would be better to see full `nginx.conf`, by the way, I was talking about `accept_mutex` directive, and I don't see it here.